# Creating labels and entries in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I'm trying to make a for loop that makes labels and entries, using a for loop. Here's the code:

```
r = 1   #r == row
c = 0   #c == column
n = 1   #n == number
a = 2   #a == checking what iteration
for count in y:                                                                                 #Iterates through y, defined earlier
    if a % 2 == 0:                                                                                   #Checks if a is even
        Label(edit_recipe_window, text="Ingredient " + str(n)).grid(row=r, column=c)
        c += 1
        entry_box= Entry(edit_recipe_window)
        entry_box.grid(row=r, column=c)
        entry_box.insert(0, count)
        c = 0
        a += 1
    else:
        Label(edit_recipe_window, text="Quantity and Unit " + str(n)).grid(row=r, column=c)
        c += 1
        quantity_box = Entry(edit_recipe_window)
        quantity_box.grid(row=r, column=c)
        quantity_box.insert(0, count)
        c = 0
        r += 1
        a += 1
    n += 1
```

This produces a label of quantity + unit 2, which is not the desired out come.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Lafexlos What is wrong with it? Explain what I have done wrong, as the exampls is reproducable.

Comment: nothing is _horribly_ wrong but it would be better if you've added import(s), what are `edit_recipe_window`(which is probably Tk instance) and `y` etc.. I mean, _complete_ example which reproduces the error. By the way, I am not the downvoter but those might be reasons of downvoter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `print` for debugging, you will see you are putting your widgets on top of eachother on each `if-else` pair.

```
from tkinter import *

edit_recipe_window = Tk()
if 1:
    r = 1   #r == row
    c = 0   #c == column
    n = 1   #n == number
    a = 2   #a == checking what iteration
    y = ["count1","count2","count3","count4","count5"]
    for count in y:
        if a%2 == 0:
            print ("inside if, label values", r, c)
            Label(edit_recipe_window, text="Ingredient " + str(n)).grid(row=r, column=c)
            c += 1
            print("inside if, entry values",r,c)
            entry_box= Entry(edit_recipe_window)
            entry_box.grid(row=r, column=c)
            entry_box.insert(0, count)
            c = 0
            a += 1

        else:
            print ("inside else, label values", r, c)
            Label(edit_recipe_window, text="Quantity and Unit " + str(n)).grid(row=r, column=c)
            c += 1
            print ("inside else, entry values", r, c)
            quantity_box = Entry(edit_recipe_window)
            quantity_box.grid(row=r, column=c)
            quantity_box.insert(0, count)
            c = 0
            r += 1
            a += 1
        n += 1
```

which will output this for 5-valued `y`

```
inside if, label values 1 0  
inside if, entry values 1 1  
inside else, label values 1 0  
inside else, entry values 1 1  
inside if, label values 2 0  
inside if, entry values 2 1  
inside else, label values 2 0  
inside else, entry values 2 1  
inside if, label values 3 0  
inside if, entry values 3 1
```

As you can see, first it puts `Label` and `Entry` in `if`, then they got overwritten by `Label` and `Entry` in `else`.

You might want to use `r += 1` at the end of your `if` to get rid of overwriting your widgets.